# brunch.io and backbone: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, brunch

I am a bit confused about how brunch handles modules.

Here is the only script file I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Backbone = require('backbone');
    console.log('hi');
});
```

Here is my brunch-config.coffee:

http://ix.io/k3I

And my app/index.jade:

http://ix.io/k3J

The error I get is: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Is it because of the module definitions?

Answer (score 0):

Configure requirejs properly it should work then http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html#add

Answer (score 0):

Backbone is not wrapped into require.js module, so it's not available as a `require` module.

Use plain `Backbone` global variable.